# How to avoid NaN when using the Math.max() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying the get the maximum value in an array of numbers:

```
maxtime=Math.max.apply( Math, cnttimearr );
alert(maxtime);
```

However, I am getting `NaN` instead of the maximum value. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is `cnttimearr`?

Comment: write definition of  `cnttimearr ` also

Answer (score 5):

Read [the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).

> If at least one of arguments cannot be converted to a number, the result is `NaN`.

Make sure all the elements in the array are convertible to numbers.

```
> xs = [1, 2, '3'];
[1, 2, "3"]
> Math.max.apply(Math, xs);
3
> xs = [1, 2, 'hello'];
[1, 2, "hello"]
> Math.max.apply(Math, xs);
NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out your array `cnttimearr` that all the values should be **convertible to numbers**

```
cnttimearr= [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];    /*your array should be like this */

maxtime = Math.max.apply(Math, cnttimearr); 
/* This about equal to Math.max(cnttimearr[0], ...) or Math.max(5, 6, ..) */
alert(maxtime);
```